# Modify SEO-friendly URL for an article in Joomla 4

Tags: joomla, joomla4

I recently moved my website to Joomla 4. I am trying to change the SEO-friendly link of some articles, since I moved them under a different category. To give you an example of what I am trying to achieve, I want the links to be updated from:

```
www.mysite.www/old_category/article-1
```

to something like

```
www.mysite.www/NEW_CATEGORY/article-1
```

According to what I have found on internet, I have changed the category in the settings of these articles and also cleared the cache (System->Maintenance->Clear Cache) but that did  not help: the url of the article still uses the old category.

What am I missing?

I'd reather avoid to go to the DB and update these links manually...

Comment: Please ask all of your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

the **Joomla SEF Route** firstly look on menu which item category list or category blog (these are default handler for **SEF**), and in DB the field who handle URL is alias. its all worked on table __menu, __content, __categories.

on source look you can get direct url on.

```
$this->item->alias
```

but the joomla always use slug

```
$this->item->slug
```

on your problem.
you need change the alias on menu who handler category blog or list..
because u are  in 1st segment url.

```
www.mysite.www/**old_category**/article-1
```

if still not work, you should play with some alias in category..

**--------------**

All Cat value called CATID stored on DB __content with the id of categories. so there is no problem. because you only can modify the alias. but the id never touched.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the category appropriately then rebuild the menu. If you are using any SEF extension , you may need to check on its settings as well.